# ViewModel does not get called in MVVMCross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

In the **FundamentalView.cs**, I have click event which triggers a fragment from the bottom of the view with having options (adding a new person and new calculations).

```
 var addButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.addButton);
 addButton.Click += OnAddButtonClick;

 void OnAddButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
   var dialog = new CardDialogView();
   dialog.Show(((MainView)Activity).SupportFragmentManager, "CardDialogView");        
 }
```

**CardDialogView.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dash_add_computer"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="New Calculation"
        local:MvxBind="Click NewCalculationCommand"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dash_add_head"
        android:drawablePadding="28dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="New Person" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**CardDialogView.cs**

```
public class CardDialogView : MvxDialogFragment<CardDialogViewModel>
{
   public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedState)
   {
       ......
       return dialog ;
   }
}
```

The following corresponding ViewModel does not get called? I wonder what I am missing?

**CardDialogViewModel.cs**

```
public class CardDialogViewModel : MvxViewModel
{

    public ICommand NewCalculationCommand
    {
        get
        {
         return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<NewItemViewModel>(new { date = DateTime.Now }));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing this from the **CardDialogView.axml** layout file `xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

**CardDialogView.axml** should be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dash_add_computer"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="New Calculation"
        local:MvxBind="Click NewCalculationCommand"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dash_add_head"
        android:drawablePadding="28dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="New Person" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Think you need to set the viewmodel on the `CardDialogView` like so:

```
    void OnAddButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new CardDialogView();
        dialog.ViewModel = new CardDialogViewModel();
        dialog.Show(SupportFragmentManager, "CardDialogView"); 
    }
```

Comment: I have added already, but forgot to include in my question, it does not work

Comment: Ah cool thougth so as it probs wouldnt build, what version of MVVMCross are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 4.0

Comment: No worries happy to help.